# Reduce time complexity of game program

Tags: java, algorithm

Adam wants to watch a football game from the top of the building that is arranged in a straight line.

1. Adam can watch the football match from the top of `ith` building if
   there exists a maximum of `K[i]` buildings in front of Adam with a
   height less than or equal to the height of `ith` building.
2. If there is any building in front of Adam with a height more than
   the height of `ith` position building then he cannot see the match
   from this `ith` building.

Count the positions of buildings where Adam can see the match from the top of the buildings.

**Example:**
Both arrays have the same length.

```
B (Buildings) = [2,1,3] represents the height of buildings
K = [1,2,1]
```

**Answer:**
1

**Explanation:**

```
For B[0] = 2 we have K[0] = 1. The number of buildings in front of it that have a height smaller than or equal to 2 is 0. This is <= K[0] So Adam can see the match.

For B[1] = 1, we have K[1] = 2. The number of buildings in front of it that have a height smaller than or equal to 1 is 0. But B[0] = 2 so Adam cannot see the match.

For B[2] = 3, we have K[2] = 1. The number of buildings in front of it that have a height smaller than or equal to 3 is 2. But this value is >= K[2] i.e 1 so Adam cannot see the match

The total positions where Adam can see the match is 1.
```

**Constraints:**

```
Array size is 1 to 10^5
Each element in Arrays is 1 to 10^5
```

This is the code I tried with the time complexity of O(n^2):

```
public static int process(int[] buildings, int[] K) {
    int n = buildings.length;
    int answer = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        boolean valid = true;
        for(int j=i-1; j>=0; j--) {
            if(buildings[j] <= buildings[i]) count++;
            if (buildings[j] > buildings[i]) {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(valid && count <= K[i]) answer++;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

This program works for arrays of small size but fails for large arrays as the time complexity of my program is O(n^2).

What is the better approach to solve this and how can we reduce the time complexity?

Comment: hmm .. this feels like a repost, is it? My apologies for mis-remembering, if not :) But if yes, better not - the new is missing any comments from the previous which might (or not) contain valuable hints) and every deletion counts towards a question ban.

Comment: as to the problem (smells a bit like homework or similar assignment, is it?) a general approach might be: a) get rid of the prose and reveal the mathematical problem in mathematical terms b) find/learn an algorithm that solves the problem with the time complexity you want to achieve (you _certainly_ are not the first gnawing on it :) c) implement the algorithm in java.

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 conditions which we look on one by one but we'll start from the second:

The second condition can be interpreted as if ith building  is the highest building from any other building in front of it. this can be achieved by checking the max hight to the ith position and update it as you go.

if the second condition is true that's means you have i-1 buildings in front of the ith building that are equal or smaller than it (i instead of i-1 if you start to count from 0 like in array). so the first condition would be true only if k[i] is bigger than (i-1) you just need to compare between them.

here is the code in java:

```
import java.util.*;
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> buildings = Arrays.asList(2, 1, 3);
        List<Integer> K = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 1);
        System.out.println(process(K, buildings));
    }

    
    public static Integer process(List<Integer> K, List<Integer> buildings){
        Integer maxHightBuilding = buildings.get(0);
        Integer sum = 0;
        for(Integer i = 0; i < buildings.size(); i++){
            if(buildings.get(i) >= maxHightBuilding ){
                maxHightBuilding = buildings.get(i);
                if(i <= K.get(i)){
                    sum++;
                }
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing: I had misread the answer, but I've upvoted it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @MauricePerry I glad you got my idea, and thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think if you retain the biggest value in front of the actual index, you can just check with the value and when your index passes the biggest value you can update it.

So find the biggest value from the end of the array.

HF!

Comment: But this only solved my second point `If there is any building in front of Adam with a height more than the height of ith position building then he cannot see the match from this ith building.`. So using this approach will not reduce time complexity.

Comment: For the first point you can determinate count with your index

Comment: Can you please explain with an example how to do it

Comment: @learner just compare between the i to K[i] if i is bigger that's means the ith building has too many building infront of it (even if they are smaller) and if K[i] is equal or bigger that's mean it doesn't, i.e that condition is true.

Comment: @JackRaBeat, height less than or equal to the height of ith building this condition is missing your explanation. How to achieve this? `compare between the i to K[i] ` this is not my requirement.

Comment: @learner the comparation is because if the second condition is true that's means the ith building is bigger (or equal) than i-1 buildings (all the buildings that are infront of it) so and the second condition asks for that there'll be no more than K[i] buildings smaller than him